# Limit the total number of emails per domain / per hour / per day

Tags: windows-server-2008, email, email-server

I have Windows 2008 Server with Mail Enable Free edition with plesk 9.5. What I want is to limit each domain with total number of emails per hour / per day to avoid spam.

I know it's possible in Mail Enable Ent. Version, which is not free. (I don't want to pay right now). Is this possible or do I have to use any other script?

Is this possible in hMailserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pre-made and free solution to this at the moment, sadly.
MailEnable should provide this feature without having to buy the enterprise edition but at the moment it seem to be the only option.

Unless MailEnable ever allow us to build a license "à la carte", custom scripts parsing logs are the only way to do this.

Comment: and what about Hmail Server does this mail server have this option ?

Comment: I have not used Hmail enough but from my experience, it was not possible. Maybe the documentation hides it somewhere, http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/